# Operations carry over on next random

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe, flash-cs5, flashdevelop

```
function roll(){
randomNumber = Math.ceil(Math.random() * range);
randomNumber2 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * range);
randomNumber3 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * range);
dice1_mc.gotoAndStop(randomNumber);
dice2_mc.gotoAndStop(randomNumber2);
dice3_mc.gotoAndStop(randomNumber3);
num1 = int(randomNumber);
num2 = int(randomNumber2);
num3 = int(randomNumber3);
trace(num1);
trace(num2);
trace(num3)
}

      function AddCheck(e:MouseEvent):void {
       ans = num1+num2+num3;
       if (displayText.text == String(ans)){
        //score++;
        trace("Correct");
        trace(ans);
        displayText.text ="";
        score+=1;
        displayScore.text = String(score);
        opsymbol=0;
        RandomizeOperation();
    }else{
        trace("answer is " + ans + "------")
        clearTxt();
        //RandomizeOperation()
    }
    }


    function MultiCheck(e:MouseEvent):void {
    ans = num1*num3;
    if (displayText.text == String(ans)){
        //score++;
        trace("Correct");
        displayText.text ="";
        score+=1;
        displayScore.text = String(score);
        opsymbol=0;
        RandomizeOperation();
    }else{
        trace("answer is " + ans + "------")
        clearTxt();
        //RandomizeOperation()
    }
    }

   function SubCheck(e:MouseEvent):void {
    ans = num1-num2-num3;
    if (displayText.text == String(ans)){
        //score++;
        trace("Correct");
        trace(ans);
        displayText.text ="";
        score+=1;
        opsymbol=0;
        displayScore.text = String(score);
        RandomizeOperation();

    }else{
        trace("answer is " + ans + "------")
        clearTxt();
        //RandomizeOperation()
    }
         }


    function RandomizeOperation(){
    var oprange:uint = 2;
    opsymbol = Math.ceil(Math.random() * oprange);
    //opsymbol = 2;
        //trace(opsymbol);

      if(opsymbol == 1){
    dice2_mc.visible= true;
    trace(opsymbol + " addition");
    enterAns_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, AddCheck);
    roll();
        }
        if(opsymbol == 2){
    dice2_mc.visible= true;
    trace(opsymbol + " subtraction");
    enterAns_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, SubCheck);
    roll();
        }

            }
```

[image]

The operation carry over everytime the question changes. I dont know whats wrong.

example first question is 1+2+3 (which is 6) and the next question is Subtraction (3-3-1- RIGHT answer is suppose to be -1) but it add. i cant figure out whats wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is carrying over here. You're just not removing the eventListener for mouse **from** one type to another, instead you are **adding to** the already there MouseEvent(s). Two traces at once is a big clue:

You need inside `{ }` of your `if (opsymbol == 2)`:

```
//will remove ANY existing current listeners to some function
enterAns_btn.removeEventListener(event.type, arguments.callee);
//adds a new listener to some function for this new Check type
enterAns_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, SubCheck);
```

**Why it happens:**

```
if (opsymbol == 1)
{ 
    //CHECK ONE: enterAns_btn listens for ADD
    enterAns_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, AddCheck); 
}

if (opsymbol == 2)
{ 
    //CHECK TWO: enterAns_btn listens for SUBTRACT
    enterAns_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, SubCheck); 
}
```

Because CHECK TWO happened after CHECK ONE, At this point you're now telling Flash that **enterAns_btn** must actually do two functions on mouse click.. Essentially it heard this command:

```
enterAns_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, AddCheck); //added by check one
enterAns_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, SubCheck); //added by check two
```

And thats why you get two traces results at once.. One for adding to give you the 7 and the other for subtracting to give the -1.. Hope it helps.

Comment: Sir, what can I do to fix this? Thanks a lot. I am not familiar with enterAns_btn.removeEventListener(event.type, arguments.callee);

Comment: In your function `RandomizeOperation()` find that `if (opsymbol == 2)` part and look at answer again. You put it before `enterAns_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, SubCheck);`. It doesn't need any editing, it's a generic command for such situations to cancel-out any other already existing listeners.

Comment: is there any way I can compare my answer without passing on the first check?

Comment: OK, was this all fixed in the end or still need a solution?